# spf header information, namely Pass(mailfrom), identity, and receiver=<UNKNOWN>

Tags: spf

Is it possible, and how would I go about setting header information for my SPF implementation.

It seems to work Ok. I see the SPF header on emails received from different email addresses. However, the information in the three fields, namely, in the Pass(mailfrom), identity=mailfrom and the receiver= seem less than perfect.

Where can I set those to appear "better?"

I read through the man pages for policyd-spf, and unfortunately http://openspf.org is offline at the moment so I can't figure out more detailed information about the headers--or where the header information comes from. Maybe postfix setttings in main.cf? Will go down that path for now.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Meanwhile, you can use [archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20190225203208/http://www.openspf.org/)

Comment: Thanks for the tip. will check it out!

Answer (score 1):

I haven't figured out the mailto, mailfrom parts, but I guess those are maybe related to canonical settings within postfix, if enabled?

The last, receiver=email@hello.com can be set in the configuration file for 
/etc/postfix-policyd-spf-python/policyd-spf.conf

By adding the following line:
Hide_Receiver = No

for privacy reasons, the default is yes.

Comment: https://manpages.debian.org/testing/postfix-policyd-spf-python/policyd-spf.conf.5.en.html#HIDE_RCPT_TO_IN_RESULTS_HEADER